# Rails: Why does RSpec crash on my overridden Devise controller request spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, capybara

**Update:** Oh good grief, it was all a red herring following a bad merge. Somewhere along the line, the following for elided from a cleanup of spec/spechelper.rb

```
Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/**/*.rb"].each {|f| load f}
```

Now that this is restored, everything is working again. I suspect it was only load the flat dir, and not nested dirs, making it *look* like a namespace issue.

(I can't answer my own question as this is a new account, and I don't have the rep)

---

Original question:

Most of my RSpec/Capybara tests work fine, but I have *one* test that explodes on simply trying to visit a path, and I'm stuck on debugging.  I *suspect* it's a Namespace issue but I don't know how to address that; any help gratefully received.

The entire test is:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe 'Registrations' do
  context 'when debugging the blocking issue' do
    it 'this minimal test should pass' do
      visit new_user_registration_path
    end
  end
end
```

The error message is:

> $ bin/rspec spec/requests/users/registrations_spec.rb
>
> Failures:
>
> 1) Users::Registrations when debugging the blocking issue this minimal test should pass
>       Failure/Error: visit new_user_registration_path
>       LoadError:
>         Expected app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb to define Users::RegistrationsController
>       # ./spec/requests/users/registrations_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in '

So the error is **Expected users/registrations_controller.rb to define Users::RegistrationsController**, that's not much help!

The controller is an overridden Devise controller, and it looks like:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super
    # My extra code here
  end
end
```

My routes redirect devise a little:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'users/registrations' } do
  get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end
```

I'm utterly stuck on trying to find a root cause for the 'Expected foo.rb to define Foo' error'; I can't get an insight into what's really causing my issue.

What would you do next to debug this?

---

David suggested a backtrace might help; as far as I can see, I don't have an error preventing loading, looks to me (but I'm a rails noob) like all ActiveSupport blocks. Here it is for interest:

```
  1) Users::Registrations when debugging the blocking issue this minimal test should pass
     Failure/Error: visit new_user_registration_path

     LoadError:
       Expected app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb to define Users::RegistrationsController
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:490:in `load_missing_constant'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `block in const_missing'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `each'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `const_missing'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:124:in `block in constantize'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:123:in `each'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:123:in `constantize'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:528:in `block in initialize'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:550:in `yield'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:550:in `default'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:550:in `[]'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:61:in `controller_reference'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:46:in `controller'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:25:in `call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:41:in `call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `block in call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `block in recognize'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:110:in `optimized_each'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95:in `recognize'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:531:in `call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/sass-3.1.12/lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:54:in `call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/warden-1.1.0/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/warden-1.1.0/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/warden-1.1.0/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:243:in `call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195:in `context'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190:in `call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:326:in `call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:62:in `call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:477:in `call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392:in `_run_call_callbacks'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:101:in `call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:455:in `call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:52:in `block in call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:46:in `each'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:46:in `call'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rack-test-0.6.1/lib/rack/mock_session.rb:30:in `request'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rack-test-0.6.1/lib/rack/test.rb:219:in `process_request'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rack-test-0.6.1/lib/rack/test.rb:57:in `get'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/capybara-1.1.2/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:62:in `process'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/capybara-1.1.2/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:21:in `visit'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/capybara-1.1.2/lib/capybara/rack_test/driver.rb:32:in `visit'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/capybara-1.1.2/lib/capybara/session.rb:157:in `visit'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/capybara-1.1.2/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:161:in `visit'
     # ./spec/requests/users/registrations_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in '
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:51:in `block in run'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:110:in `with_around_hooks'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:48:in `run'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:306:in `block in run_examples'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:302:in `map'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:302:in `run_examples'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:274:in `run'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:275:in `block in run'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:275:in `map'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:275:in `run'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in run'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:24:in `map'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:24:in `block in run'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:12:in `report'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:21:in `run'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run_in_process'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:66:in `rescue in run'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:62:in `run'
     # .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@foo/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
```

Comment: Actually, you can always answer questions and accept answers to your own questions. You can't *comment* on questions until you get to 50 rep, though. Typically, poster answering his own question posts it as an answer and then accepts it so that people searching will see the question has an accepted answer.  Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: "Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 3 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead." I'll clean this up tomorrow! And I've been here before, but on different corporate identities, pity to lose rep but it's 'cleaner' in the long run when there's IP agreements etc to navigate.

Comment: Hmmm... anonymous users can answer your question before you can. Kind of a perverse incentive there.  Anyway, welcome *back* to SO.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you type `bin/rspec --help`, you'll see a list of options and switches you can add to the command, including the `--backtrace` switch, which tells RSpec to show you the full backtrace. If you run `bin/rspec spec/requests/users/registrations_spec.rb --backtrace` you should see precisely where the error is coming from.

HTH,
David

Comment: It's verbose, certainly, but it's not helped me! It's all ActiveSupport blocks. I'll post below question in a second. We think it's due to namespaces somehow as this is the only one with a controller namespaced.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Oh good grief, it was all a red herring following a bad merge. Somewhere along the line, the following for elided from a cleanup of spec/spechelper.rb

```
Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/**/*.rb"].each {|f| load f}
```

Now that this is restored, everything is working again. I suspect it was only load the flat dir, and not nested dirs, making it look like a namespace issue.