# Devise & Rspec Test Integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, devise

I'm trying to run tests with Devise and Rspec and have been unsuccessful thus far - any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
rake spec:requests --trace
```

gives me this error

```
`/Users/carl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/requests/users_spec.rb
/Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:503:in ‘load_missing_constant': Expected /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/devise-2.1.2/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb to define DeviseController (LoadError)
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in ‘block in const_missing'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in ‘each'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in ‘const_missing'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/devise-2.1.2/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:1:in ‘<top (required)>'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in ‘require'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in ‘block in require'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in ‘load_dependency'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in ‘require'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in ‘require_or_load'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in ‘load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in ‘block in const_missing'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in ‘each'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in ‘const_missing'
    from /Users/carl/rails_projects/my_rails_app_name/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:14:in ‘<class:ApplicationController>'
    from /Users/carl/rails_projects/my_rails_app_name/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in ‘<top (required)>'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in ‘require'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in ‘block in require'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in ‘load_dependency'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in ‘require'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in ‘require_or_load'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in ‘load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in ‘block in const_missing'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in ‘each'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in ‘const_missing'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in ‘block in constantize'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in ‘each'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in ‘constantize'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:54:in ‘constantize'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/devise-2.1.2/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:2:in ‘<top (required)>'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in ‘require'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in ‘block in require'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in ‘load_dependency'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in ‘require'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in ‘require_or_load'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in ‘load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in ‘block in const_missing'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in ‘each'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in ‘const_missing'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/devise-2.1.2/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb:1:in ‘<top (required)>'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in ‘require'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in ‘block in require'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in ‘load_dependency'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in ‘require'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in ‘require_or_load'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in ‘depend_on'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in ‘require_dependency'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in ‘block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in ‘each'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in ‘block in eager_load!'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in ‘each'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in ‘eager_load!'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in ‘each'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in ‘all'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:434:in ‘eager_load!'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in ‘block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in ‘instance_exec'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in ‘run'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in ‘block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in ‘each'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in ‘run_initializers'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in ‘initialize!'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in ‘method_missing'
    from /Users/carl/rails_projects/my_rails_app_name/config/environment.rb:5:in ‘<top (required)>'
    from /Users/carl/rails_projects/my_rails_app_name/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in ‘require'
    from /Users/carl/rails_projects/my_rails_app_name/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in ‘<top (required)>'
    from /Users/carl/rails_projects/my_rails_app_name/spec/requests/users_spec.rb:1:in ‘require'
    from /Users/carl/rails_projects/my_rails_app_name/spec/requests/users_spec.rb:1:in ‘<top (required)>'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in ‘load'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in ‘block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in ‘map'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in ‘load_spec_files'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in ‘run'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in ‘run'
    from /Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in ‘block in autorun'
rake aborted!
/Users/carl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/requests/users_spec.rb failed
/Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:137:in ‘block (2 levels) in initialize'
/Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:60:in ‘verbose'
/Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:127:in ‘block in initialize'
/Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in ‘call'
/Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in ‘block in execute'
/Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in ‘each'
/Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in ‘execute'
/Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in ‘block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/carl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in ‘mon_synchronize'
/Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in ‘invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in ‘invoke'
/Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in ‘invoke_task'
/Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in ‘block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in ‘each'
/Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in ‘block in top_level'
/Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in ‘standard_exception_handling'
/Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in ‘top_level'
/Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in ‘block in run'
/Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in ‘standard_exception_handling'
/Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in ‘run'
/Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in ‘<top (required)>'
/Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/rake:19:in ‘load'
/Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/rake:19:in ‘<main>'
`
```

Gemfile for :development, :test
`gem 'sqlite3'`
`gem 'rspec-rails'`
`gem 'capybara'`

spec/requests/user_spec.rb

```
> `require 'spec_helper'
> 
> describe "Users" do
>   describe "GET /" do
>     it "goes to homepage" do
>       visit '/'
>       response.status.should be(200)
>     end   
>   end 
> end`
```

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec'
#require 'capybara/rails'


# Note: To create integration test: $rails g integration_test blah --integration-tool=rspec


# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|

  # Include devise in Rspec tests
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller

  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend helped me figure this one out. In my application controller I was overriding Devise with the below code. Commenting this out allowed `rake spec:requests` to pass successfully.

```
# ===============================================
  # == Commented this out to make rspec tests work
  # ===============================================
  # Override Devise create session controller
  # Devise::SessionsController.class_eval do
    # def create
    #  resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    #     set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    #     sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    #     @sign_in_path = after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    #  end
    # end
```

Thank you again for your time and help!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what is going wrong, but a quick search for LoadError and the "Expected ... to define" pattern brought up a few relevant discussions.

- [Expected ... to Define](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/107385)
- [Rails 3.1 — 'load_missing_contant': Expected ... to define ... (LoadError)](http://tesoriere.com/2011/05/28/rails-3.1---%27load_missing_contant%27--expected-...-to-define-...--loaderror-/)
- [Expected x.rb to define X (LoadError)](http://icebergist.com/posts/expected-xrb-to-define-x-loaderror)
- [Rails: Why does RSpec crash on my overridden Devise controller request spec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560726/rails-why-does-rspec-crash-on-my-overridden-devise-controller-request-spec)

From the first link:

> The error message is misleading. Expected foo.rb to define Foo usually
>   just means that something bad happened when loading foo.rb (syntax
>   errors, missing constant etc...). You can usually get a better error
>   message by just typing Foo into script/console

The error is coming directly from Devise, so perhaps there is some naming conflict in your controllers with the devise controllers? I don't use devise so I don't really know much about how it works. Although I doubt that it's the problem, have a look at the file `/Users/carl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/devise-2.1.2/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb` and make sure it's not corrupted. You might try to reinstall the gem in rvm.

Comment: Agreed. I expect you inadvertedly edited the file? Just uninstall and reinstall the devise gem and that should help.

Comment: Thanks for your help Shioyama - tried doing that and it's still not working. I'm running out of ideas of what else there is to do =/

Comment: Although it might seem a bit drastic, if you're really getting nowhere you might try re-installing rvm altogether. I can't think of anything else from the info here.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info - I'll work on rvm tomorrow. Will also try to create a test project with devise to see if I can make it work. Thanks for your time and help Shioyama.